# What specific benefits can we get by using SparkSQL to access Hive tables compared to using JDBC to read tables from SQL server?

Tags: azure, hadoop, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I just got this question while designing the storage part for a Hadoop-based platform. If we want to have data scientists to have access to the tables which have already been stored in a relational database (e.g.SQL-server of a Azure Virtual Machine), then will there be any particular benefits if we import the tables from SQL-server to HDFS (e.g. WASB) and create Hive tables on top of them?

In other words, since Spark allows users to read data from other databases using JDBC,is there any performance improvement if we persist the tables from the database in appropriate format (avro, parquet etc.) in HDFS and use SparkSQL to access them using HQL?

I am sorry if this question has been asked, I have done some research but could not get a comparison between the two methodologies.

Comment: Your title doesn't agree witn your question.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry I make the confusion. Can you comment more on which part disagrees? I can then modify the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be a big performance improvement as the data is local (assuming Spark is running on same Hadoop cluster where the data is stored on HDFS). Using JDBC if the actions/processing performed is interactive then user has to wait for the data to be loaded through JDBC from another machine (N/W latency and IO throughput) whereas if that is done upfront then user (data scientist) can concentrate on performing the actions straight away.